# Access parent view's variable from child view in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-view

I'm using ZF2's View component as standalone for my project like this:

```
$renderer = new PhpRenderer;
$resolver = new Resolver\AggregateResolver();
$stack = new Resolver\TemplatePathStack(array(
    'script_paths' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/view'
    )
));
$resolver->attach($stack);
$renderer->setResolver($resolver);

$model1 = new ViewModel;
$model1->setTemplate('template1');
$model1->setVariable('key', 'value');

$model2 = new ViewModel;
$model2->setTemplate('template2');

$model1->addChild($model2, 'child');

echo $renderer->render($model1);
```

It works like charm. The child renders in model1. But the problem is, how can i access model1's variable `key` in model2?

Comment: I'm too lazy for an actual answer, but this post will help you a lot: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/access-view-variables-in-another-view-model/ he explains how to access child vars in parent, but it works the same way the other way around ;)

Comment: Thanks but i found it already with google :) But $this->viewModel()->getRoot() returns null for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Zend\View\Helper\ViewModel` to access a common root view model, and possibly traverse the whole view model tree from that.

Just set the root itself:

```
// right after you instantiated $model1
$modelHelper = $renderer->plugin('view_model');
$modelHelper->setRoot($model1);
```

And now `$this->viewModel()->getRoot()` will return `$model1` in every view template.

You can peek at how this is dealt with by default in [Zend\Mvc\View\Http\ViewManager](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.2.4/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/ViewManager.php#L179-L198)